# WinForm Control BeginInvoke/Invoke Issue

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c++-cli, invoke, begininvoke

I am trying to write a multithreaded WinForm in C++/CLI app using VS2012.

I know that only the UI thread can update a control and I have been using delegates and the invoke methods.  However, I have run into a memory access issue when using BeginInvoke that I do not see when using Invoke.

Delegate Function:

```
public: delegate void pictureboxShowDelegate(int tChannelNumber,System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^,System::Drawing::Bitmap^ colorImage);
```

Called Function:

```
void DrawCVImageShow(int tChannelNumber, System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ PBox, System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b)
{
    if(PBox->InvokeRequired)
    {
        pictureboxShowDelegate^ d = gcnew pictureboxShowDelegate(this,&MyForm::DrawCVImageShow);
        PBox->Invoke(d,tChannelNumber,PBox,b);
    }
    else
    {
        System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics = PBox->CreateGraphics();
        System::Drawing::RectangleF rect(0,0,(float)PBox->Width,(float)PBox->Height);
    graphics->DrawImage(b,rect);
    }
}
```

If called this way, it works with no problem.
If I substitute BeginInvoke for Invoke, I get an AccessViolationException.
Clearly, this has to do with the garbage collection of the parameters but I simply can't figure this one out.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No, not garbage collection.  More like is that `b` was created from an image source like a camera, provided to you by a callback.  The *unmanaged* pixel data becoming invalid after the callback returns.  Not disclosing the image source makes it impossible to answer correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like whatever is calling `DrawCVImageShow` in the first place is [Disposing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z.aspx) the bitmap immediately after `DrawCVImageShow` returns.

If that's the case, there are a couple possiblities:

- Make it so that `DrawCVImageShow` is the one responsible for Disposing the bitmap, not whatever calls `DrawCVImageShow`. (Simple solution, though probably not the best from an engineering solution: The thing that created the bitmap should generally be responsible for disposing it, and it makes `DrawCVImageShow` a less general method.)
- Make a [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone.aspx) of the bitmap, and dispose that one after it's been used. This is the more proper solution, in my opinion, but it does make things a little bit more complicated. You now need two versions of `DrawCVImageShow`, one that disposes the bitmap (for BeginInvoking), and one that doesn't (the method you have now). This also means you'll have two copies of the bitmap in memory when a BeginInvoke is needed; hopefully these bitmaps are not so large that this is an issue.